# Como ordernar um relacionamento hasMany com base em um relacionamento hasOne contido no segundo nível no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Possuo a classe Perguntas que tem um relacionamento hasMany com a classe Respostas (Uma pergunta pode ter várias respostas). A classe Respostas possui um relacionamento hasOne com a classe categoria (cada resposta pertence a uma categoria).

```
class Perguntas 
{
    public function respostas()
    {
         return $this->hasMany(Respostas::class, 'pergunta_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
         return $this->hasMany(Tags::class, 'pergunta_id', 'id');
    }

}

class Respostas 
{
    public function categoria()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(Categorias::class, 'id', 'categoria_id');
    }

}
```

Realizando a consulta abaixo:

```
$perguntas = Perguntas::with(['respostas.categoria', 'tags'])->latest()->paginate(10);
```

Como eu posso obter o vetor de respostas ordenado de acordo com o nome da categoria?

Answer (score -1):

Para pegar só as respostas ordenadas pela categoria da para usar o método sortBy(), ficando assim:

```
$respostas = Resposta::with("categoria")->get()->sortBy(fn ($resposta) => $resposta->categoria->name)->values();
```

O sortBy() recebe um parâmetro podendo ser uma função anônima, com isso, dá para acessar a categoria da resposta. Nesse exemplo eu ordenei baseado no campo *name* da categoria.

Se você quiser colocar essa ordenação na mesma query onde você pega as perguntas, ficaria algo assim:

```
$perguntas = Pergunta::with(['respostas.categoria', 'tags'])->latest()->paginate(10);


$perguntasCollection = $perguntas->getCollection();


$perguntasOrdenadas = $perguntasCollection->map(function ($item) { 
    $item->respostas->sortBy(fn ($resposta) => $resposta->categoria->name)->values();
    return $item;
})->values();
```

O método paginate() retorna um objeto do tipo *Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator* e para pegar os resultados como uma collection é preciso usar o método getCollection(). Após isso é só colocar o mesmo trecho de código usado para ordenar as respostas dentro de uma funcao map().

Ou então, se você quiser mudar sua paginação para depois de executar a query toda, ficaria assim:

```
$perguntas = Pergunta::with(['respostas.categoria', 'tags'])->latest()->get();

$perguntasOrdenadas = $perguntas->map(function ($item) { 
    $item->respostas->sortBy(fn ($resposta) => $resposta->categoria->name)->values();
    return $item;
})->forPage(1,10);
```